# python days until specified date without date library

Tags: python, date

```
MONTHLEN = [ 0, # No month zero
    31, # 1. January
    28, # 2. February (ignoring leap years)
    31, # 3. March
    30, # 4. April
    31, # 5. May
    30, # 6. June
    31, # 7. July
    31, # 8. August
    30, # 9. September
    31, #10. October
    30, #11. November
    31, #12. December
    ]
def count_normal_year(year, start_month, start_date, end_month, end_date):
    day_count=0
    if start_month == end_month and start_date==end_date:
        print(0)
    else:
        day_count+=(MONTHLEN[start_month]-start_date)
    next_start_month_index=start_month + 1
        for months in range(MONTHLEN[next_start_month_index, MONTHLEN[end_month]):
            day_count+=MONTHLEN[months]
    day_count +=end_date
        print(day_count)
```

I'm not allowed to use the date library.

my idea for this loop is to subtract the days left in the starting month, and then loop through MONTHLEN starting at MONTHLEN index of the next starting month up until the end month.

IE 1 2 12 1
it would give 29 then start February first and add the total days of all months up until December (but not including December) then add the end date
so 28 +31 +30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30 for adding the total days in the month to get me to December then add the end date of 1

I'm not sure the correct syntax to code my idea

Comment: Looping is the lazy and inefficient way of solving a problem like this. You need to get a day number for each date, then subtract them.

Comment: Also as a heads up your current logic doesn't take **leap year** into account.

Comment: What should your program do if the start month is, eg November and the end month is March?

Comment: I was going to refactor the code for leap years,
I need to figure out reverse months too